# Sum values according to an index array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays of the same dimension:

```
a = np.array([ 1,  1, 2,  0, 0, 1])
b = np.array([50, 51, 6, 10, 3, 2])
```

I want to sum the elements of `b` according to the indices in `a`.

The `i`th element of the matrix I want will be the sum of all values `b[j]` such that `a[j]==i`.

So the result should be a 3-dimensional array of `[10 + 3, 50 + 51 + 2, 6]`

Is there a numpy way to do this? I have some very large arrays that I need to sum like this over multiple dimensions, so it would NOT be convenient to to have to perform explicit loops.

Comment: Can you explain the procedure ? 3rd dimension ? it's a bit unclear maybe ?

Comment: @Anmol_uppal I believe another way to put it is that OP wants to group the elements in `b` using the their positionally corresponding elements in `a` as unique identifier, and then compute the sum of the elements in `b` per unique identifier.

Comment: Yes that's right. I added a clarifying sentence.

Comment: @Bill Check out the answer from @njzk2 - it's not a `numpy` solution per se, but it seems pretty easy to wrap up in a function that accepts `a` and `b` as parameters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[numpy.bincount](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) has a `weights` parameter which does just what you need:

```
In [36]: np.bincount(a, weights=b)
Out[36]: array([  13.,  103.,    6.])
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I'm looking for. To add to this, it is also possible to use `apply_along_axis` with `bincount` in cases where `b` is of higher dimension than a.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are not using numpy, something as simple as :

```
res = [0]*len(set(a))
for i, v in enumerate(b):
    res[a[i]] += v
```

Assuming the indices in `a` are always 0-based and a continuous sequence.

Comment: I'd think that the point of asking about this using np (numpy) is to avoid Python iteration over the arrays and to use Numpy vector functions to do this quickly.  Any time you're iteratively over Numpy arrays you're probably taking a huge performance penalty.

Comment: @JimDennis: I often try to suggest an alternative to numpy functions, in case someone does not use it. (but I agree with you, when using numpy, use numpy)